# Bucle de background step?

Tags: javascript, html, css

no consigo incorporar el bucle en mi codigo; Es un bucle para que cada vez que hago doble click se cambie el background de mi item sunbed. necesito que cuando llegue al sunbed.step4 y realize un dobleclick vuelva automaticamente al sunbed.step1 asi continuamente.
Codigo completo; https://codepen.io/Kawasaki93/full/NWyJdVx

```
    $('.toggle').dblclick(function () {  let step = $(this).data('actual-step') || 1;
                                                   
$(this).addClass('step'+ step);
$(this).removeClass('actual-step');
$(this).data('actual-step', step + 1 );
                        
                            
});
```

**CSS**

```
    .sunbed.step1 {
  background:LightSeaGreen; 
    /*ocupado*/
     }

.sunbed.step2 {
  background: red;
  /*pagado*/
  }
.sunbed.step3 {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, LightSeaGreen 50%, DarkCyan 50%); 
  /*ocupado con 3 hamacas cada lado*/
      }
.sunbed.step4 {
  background:linear-gradient(to left, LightSeaGreen 50%, green 50%); 
  /*ocupado 1 persona sola*/
     }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De que bucle estas hablando? Todo tu codigo relevante debe estar en la pregunta. No esta claro cual es tu problema.

Comment: Hola gbianchi necesito que cuando llegue al sunbed.step4 y realize un dobleclick  vuelva automaticamente al sunbed.step1 asi continuamente

Comment: Vuelva que cosa? a donde tiene que volver? estas siendo poco claro, como si realmente conocieramos tu sistema. Para mi, volver, requeriria que hubiera 4 pantallas y volvieras a la primera. Que es volver en el contexto de esta pregunta? volver a que? a donde se estaba yendo? Entiendes que no lo hago de maldad, pero no esta nada claro que hace tu sistema o que pretendes que haga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergio, lo que estás haciendo son dos cosas confusas...

1. Haces un removeClass de `actual-step` que en realidad es una propiedad de data, y no una clase. Además, no sé muy bien si te refieres a eso exactamente o debería ser un `attr` de tu elemento (no sé exactamente porque no se ve el código)
2. Incrementas 1 a `step`, que en realidad estaría bien. Pero quieres un ciclo, así que cuando esté en 4 querrás que vuelva a 1.

A ver si te vale lo siguiente:

```
$('.toggle').dblclick(function () {  
    let arr_steps = [1,2,3,4],                              ///posibilidades de steps por css
      step = parseInt($(this).data('actual-step')) || 1,    ///step tal y como está al hacer click
      nuevo_step = (step==arr_steps.length)?1:step+1;       ///nuevo valor para actual-step: uno más, o que vuelva a 1

    $(this).removeClass('step'+step);

    $(this).addClass('step'+ nuevo_step);
    $(this).data('actual-step', nuevo_step );
});
```

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que necesito.muchas gracias